# How do I run code I have written in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner, all I have done is practiced writing code in Codecademy. After extensive searches of google for how to run a .js file, I turned up nothing. I assume I am asking the wrong question, and I am sure it is simple, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You need to put it in an HTML file and run it in a browser.

Comment: It depends on the platform you've written the JavaScript for. The answer is different for a Node.js application, a Windows Scripting Host application, a Chrome extension, a script designed to be embedded in a webpage and so on.

Comment: Firefox has a WebIDE you can use. `Shift + F8`

Comment: https://blog.udemy.com/javascript-hello-world/
first result

Comment: JS is executed when you include it as a  `<script>` in a html page by your browser, or you can use node.js to run a script from the command line

Comment: Just add the code inside the `<script>` tag (ex. `<script>alert("Hello World!");</script>` ) and put it inside an HTML file (ex. `index.html` ) and run it inside a browser! ^^

Comment: Press F12 in a modern browser.

Answer (score 15):

1. open an editor. Simplest one is notepad
2. Write basic HTML there like below

   ```html
   <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
           Hello World!
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Add a script tag and write your js inside it  like below

   ```html
   <html>
       <head>
           <script> 
               alert("hello");
           </script>
       </head>
       <body>
           Hello World!
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. or you can write your js code in a file and save as .js file and link that in the above code

   ```html
   <html>
       <head>
           <script src="myScript.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
           Hello World!
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. Save this as yourfile.HTML and open in any browser

Here's a link to learn more: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still confused though. When I tried to use the code from the fourth step in your answer, all it shows is "Hello World!" although myScript.js had other things. What am I missing?

Comment: @user2607534 I would request you to post the contents of your js file in the question. Or maybe separate question. As a tip, i can tell you this-> If you are using Chrome,on your browser right click and choose `Inspect Element`. This should open dev toolbar. Click on `console` and see if there were any errors in js file.

Comment: `<head></head>` can be removed.

Answer (score 4):

First install and setup Nodejs in your machine. Then write your javascript and save it in a folder. Open the command prompt inside the folder and write the command to execute.

```
node a.js
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an addition to previous answers.

If you want to practice simple JavaScript instructions and code snippets like you did in Codecademy you can use:

- Your browser console, I believe pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> will open it on all popular browsers
- [JS Console](http://jsconsole.com/)
- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)'s [REPL](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/REPL/how-to-use-nodejs-repl) ([installation instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node))

Answer (score 2):

Run javascript in your browser simply use this methods:

**1**. use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

**2**. use developer console your browser (how to open console in Chrome/Firefox/Safari you can read in Wiki)

**3**. write your own file with extention .html and put it:

```
<script>
    alert('Hello world!');
</script>
```

into the file, save file and open on browser.

Every method have own benefits when you discover JS. We developers use every day all of this methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are to create a file with extension .html, so open up notepad or similar program and write the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //Your code
    alert("You made your fist javascript!");
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Your javascript actions and codes go inside the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

When running a .js file, you just need to add it in your web page. Example.

If you have this as the content of a .js file say hello.js

```
alert('Yow!');
```

to use it, you create an HTML file

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```