# Search text in html by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some html like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Something</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide" id="show">Protected</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to display or hide/show an element via JavaScipt if html has "Something" in its text. How can I do that? I need this for my Wordpress page.

Comment: Do you has that some thing in side certain id or class ?

Comment: Your question title not inline with your description. Title saying search html element but description saying text. What you looking for, the html element which contains the "Something" text or else?

Comment: Do you want to search the whole page or specifically target `div`? Also, please ensure to do some research into how to select an element, how to search it's inner html or text and how to show hide it using JavaScript. Then post the code you have issues with so we can help. - [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - [**How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users before posting a Question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/448144)

Comment: Protected - url to youtube channel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without using jQuery:

```
var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var hasText = content.indexOf("Something")!==-1;
if (hasText) {
    document.getElementById("show").style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById("show").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need. How to run this code after refresh or display a website ? http://dev.suszek.info/js.html

Comment: Do you mean: "How to run javascript code?"? If so: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887065/how-do-i-run-code-i-have-written-in-javascript)

Comment: Whatever. When I change string "Something" it's dosent work but in fiddle it's works.

Comment: Please check http://dev.suszek.info/js.html IF I change text from something to something2 the js dosent add display: none to html element.

Comment: Indeed. That's because you search for 'Something'. Not for 'Something2'

Comment: So it should go to else and add display: none. Am I right ?